# CSS Dropdown Error In Safari (IPhone) Browser

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

www.milknhny.co.uk/TestTheme

Ive just had a look at this, and it appears that my CSS drop down is not working on my iphone.

I havent put anything else within the CSS and a little confused as to why this would not be working.

Please could i have a pointer as to what could be causing the issue?

thanks
Kirsty

Comment: Is it because you can't HOVER on a smartphone/tablet?

Comment: Hi Billy, the styling is also not working thats the thing, not so much the hover, i did read that on some browsers it doesnt like it, but i can post my css styling and see if this is the issue, it was working fine a few days ago so i cant understand why it wouldnt be

Comment: Seems to work okay on an iPad that I have here. Clicking on Services of Hermes Bags causing the dropdown to appear. On my phone (a Nexus 4 using Chrome) when I click those links the dropdown only appears momentarily then the page clicks through.

Comment: hmmm, and the stylings there? Must be a slight techy glitch then, as it was working. I will try on Ipad later also. Thanks for comments Billy

Answer (score -1):

I had problems with this too. I did enough research to find a solution.

It doesn't work on the iPhone because mobile safari does not support hover (because you can't technically hover on a touchscreen).

The solution is to add: `onmouseover=""` inside the `<li>` tag.

I would assume this could work for any hover problems in HTML but I haven't tested it. Please refer to this link. This guy deserves all the credit.

Example:

```
<ul>
   <li onmouseover=""> </li>
</ul>
```

[Source URL](http://www.cotsweb.com/blog/css-dropdown-menus-dont-work-on-iphones-ipads-275.html)

Comment: formatting is really bad on this answer. Please surround any code in a code block. Tried to fix but it's too messed up

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried many things, but adding this onmouseover="" saved me!